# ASP.NET pdf converter

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I am looking for easy solution to convert  documents from one format(doc, html, xls...) to pdf in ASP.NET.

Is the iTextSharp a good choise? Can iTextSharp convert  documents from one format to pdf?

What library can your suggest me to use?

Comment: Itextsharp is good and easiest. I use it for all my sites

Comment: Can you provide me an example to convert from doc to pdf using iTextSharp?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using winnovative for all my PDF generation for the past few years:

http://www.winnovative-software.com/

Fair few good features, and simple to implement, if you don't mind paying for a license.

Comment: It doesn't work with doc files, only with html. Is there any generic solution?

Answer (score 0):

The default standard for this task should be [Microsoft Office SharePoint Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff181518.aspx). Another option would be using Microsoft Office applications from ASP.NET with [Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757), combined with a PDF Printer (you will need a copy of Microsoft Office installed on the server). There are many PDF printers outthere ([Cute PDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp) for example), but if you can afford a commercial option I recommend [Amyuni PDF Converter](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfconverter/features.html). There are samples of Word/Excel to PDF conversion using Office+Automation with this product.

Comment: Although a good product, why is this related to SharePoint if all he is running is ASP.NET?

Comment: @Muhimbi Microsoft recommends using Microsoft Office SharePoint Server instead of plain Automation with Office for server side tasks. Take a look at the link about Automation in my answer for more details.

Comment: Hi @yms. I am very much aware of SharePoint, but it doesn't convert all file formats. A (very expensive) version of SharePoint 2010 can do MS-Word to PDF Conversion using an extremely limited API. Just getting SharePoint in to do some conversion from an ASP.NET application is overkill to say the least, although I am sure there are scenarios where it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working as Developer Evangelist with Aspose. And I would like to share with you that you may try [Aspose.Total for .NET product suite](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.total-for-.net/default.aspx), which allows you to convert various file formats (DOC/DOCX/PPT/PPTX/XSL/HTML etc.) into PDF format. You may also select components of your choice. Complete samples, tutorials and support are also available for these components.

Please note that these components are standard .NET assemblies and you can use them either in ASP.NET or Windows Forms applications.

Answer (score -1):

Give the [Muhimbi PDF Converter Services](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx) a look. It installs in your environment as a scalable and robust Windows Service and has specifically been designed for use from server based applications such as ASP.NET.

It comes with a [friendly web services based interface](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html) that allows it to be used from most modern environments such as Java and .NET. It supports all common as well as some not so common file formats. [Watermarking](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/06/using-awesome-new-watermarking-features.html) and PDF Security is included as well. If you have SharePoint in your environment then a [SharePoint optimised version](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx) is available as well.

Disclaimer, I have worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply. Having said that, it works great.